# SemanticUi Dropdown Function Throws off template function

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, semantic-ui

Semantic UI [Dropdown function](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html) throws of my template event function.

The setup, in Meteor 1.2:

**Home Template:**

```
<select id="foo" class="ui dropdown">
  <option value="">Gender</option>
  <option value="1">Male</option>
  <option value="0">Female</option>
</select>
<script>$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();</script>
```

**Template events:**

```
'change #foo': function(e){
  var selected = $(e.target).val();
  console.log(selected);
}
```

If I comment out the script, in the Home Template, I get my log message but not so if not commented. Any hack around this?

Comment: try adding the dropdown init `$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();` to `Template.onRendered` and to listen to change events your probably need to check the SemanticUI they might have a different way to listen to change and you can do it as well inside the onRendered function

Comment: Sorry, Mark. I'm a bit new. I've created `Template.name.onRendered({});`, moved the script inside but still nothing?

Comment: added an answer to help you with an example

Comment: Thanks. I'm on mobile and will try this out in a hour or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you want to initialize external plugins (semantic-ui dropdown) you should init it inside `onRendered` and here are the options for the dropdown plugin I used the `onChange` callback

http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/settings

Something like this:

```
Template.name.onRendered(function () {
  $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
    onChange: function (val, text) {
        console.log(val);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Works like a breeze! Thanks!